# A tag for "can be run on the web"?

Tags: discussion

Can anyone suggest a short tag for "can be run on the web" ?
For example, a site where students could run hands-on e.g. clustering on a standard dataset or two would be useful; a tag would help people looking for such. (There must be quite a few sites with downloadable R scripts and data and tutorial too, what tag for those ?)

Comment: If this is not a new tag proposal, it is rather a topic for [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold).

Answer (score 1):

We can create sets of synonyms if one tag alone is not obvious.  The two words that first come to my mind are `applet` and `web`.  The latter sounds almost too generic to be useful.

As we [learned painfully](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/841/the-analytical-derivation-tag) last month, it is not a good idea to create and apply tags in a wholesale fashion, retroactively.  Let a tag emerge from a specific question rather than an abstract sense that the tag might be useful.

Comment: I agree that tags should come from real examples, real use; how about "web-app", see if anybody uses it ?  (There's I think a deep split between most academics' paper culture, and the web / learn-by-doing / havent-read-it-but-saw-the-movie culture; it's not at all clear to me how to take advantage of the latter -- again, need real examples.)

Comment: I would call it a webserver...

Comment: @mbq "webserver" has a more specific meaning.  For instance, an applet might run on the client machine, not the server.  Also, "webserver" is a term that focuses on the technology--and therefore has its rightful place on a tech-oriented site rather than a stats-oriented site--whereas the concept to be captured here concerns the statistical service being provided (i.e., software capabilities via a web page).